# Will ubuntu stop the Plasma rendering if I switch my monitor off?

Tags: performance, plasma

Will ubuntu / kubuntu-desktop continue rendering the UI if I lock the screen and switch my monitor off?

I have installed kubuntu-desktop and now my PC fan is always on and very loud. Even if the screen is locked and monitors are off.

Ubuntu 16.04
8GB Ram
i5 Intel processor

Comment: Will a tree in the middle of a forest make noise if it falls and there's no one to hear it? This seems to me more like an XY problem, you could start better with describing what hardware you have, is this a dual boot system, Ubuntu release, installed updates?

Comment: I would just know how is it solved in general.

Comment: It seems your problem is that after installing kubuntu, your fan is always on and very loud. If that is what you want to solve, then edit your question (and its title) accordingly. Also, run `top` (and paste the first 10 lines) to see if a program is stuck at 100% CPU usage. Maybe install `lm-sensors` to show the temperatures and fan speeds in your computer. Also have a look in `~/.xsession-errors` to see if there is a particularly ominous error message.